# How to find $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(\sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}(n+{a}_{i})}-n\right)$?

Tags: limits

I think it is zero;
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(\sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}(n+{a}_{i})}-n\right)$$
we can make that steps:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(\sqrt[m]{{n}^{m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{a_i}n\right)}-n\right)$$
and then:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(n \cdot \sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)}-n\right)$$
each bracket aspires to unit
so we have: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (n-n)$$
and.. 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (0) = 0$$

Comment: Some of your LaTeX delimiters didn't match up. I fixed them but I hope the square roots and parentheses are in the places you wanted them to be ...

Comment: What are the $a_i$ in your limit?

Comment: And what is $n?$

Comment: Not sure what the last two equalities are supposed to mean, but from $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(n \sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)}-n\right)$ you can only get a $0 \cdot \infty$ type thing, after factoring $n$. But every such indeterminate form can be transformed into a more managable one, for instance by writing $n=\frac{1}{1/n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard part is
showing that
$ P_n
=\sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)}
\to 1$
as $n \to \infty$.

If $n > km\max(|a_i|)$,
$1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}
< 1+\frac1{km}
$
so $P_n
<\sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac1{km}\right)}
< 1+\frac1{km}
$.

By choosing $k$ large enough,
$P_n$ can be made as close to $1$
as wanted,
showing that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(\sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}(n+{a}_{i})}-n\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(\sqrt[m]{{n}^{m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{a_i}n\right)}-n\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty } \left(n \cdot \sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)}-n\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty }\frac{ \sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=$$$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty }\frac{ \sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)}-1}{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)-1}\cdot\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{{a}_{i}}{n}\right)-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=$$$$=\frac{1}{m}\cdot\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty }\frac{1+\frac{a_1+a_2+...a_m}{n}+\frac{a_1a_2+a_2a_3+...+a_{m-1}a_m}{n^2}+...-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{a_1+a_2+...a_m}{m}.$$
We applied $$\lim_{x_n \rightarrow 0 }\frac{(1+x_n)^r-1}{x_n}=r.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\color{#ff0000}{\large\mbox{With}\ n \gg 1}$:
\begin{align}
\ln\pars{\root[m]{\prod_{i = 1}^{m}\pars{n + a_{i}}}}
&=
{1 \over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\ln\pars{n + a_{i}}
=
{1 \over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\bracks{\ln\pars{n} + \ln\pars{1 + {a_{i} \over n}}}
\sim
\ln\pars{n} + {1 \over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{a_{i} \over n}
\\[3mm]&\mbox{With}\ \ol{a} \equiv {1 \over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{i}\ \mbox{we'll get}
\\
\root[m]{\prod_{i = 1}^{m}\pars{n + a_{i}}} - n
&\sim \exp\pars{\ln\pars{n} + {\ol{a} \over n}} - n = n\pars{\expo{\ol{a}/n} - 1}
\sim n\bracks{\pars{1 + {\ol{a} \over n}} - 1} = \ol{a}
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\root[m]{\prod_{i = 1}^{m}\pars{n + a_{i}}} - n}}
=
\ol{a} = \color{#0000ff}{\large{1 \over m}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{i}}
$$