# Solving $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1) (x+a_2) \dots (x+a_n)}-x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim \limits _{x \to \infty}\bigg(\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1) (x+a_2) \dots (x+a_n)}-x\bigg)$$
We can see the limit is of type $\infty-\infty$. I don't see anything I could do here. I can only see the geometric mean which is the $n$-th root term. Can I do anything with it? Any tips on solving this?

Comment: Expand the product under the radical, keep the highest 2 terms and Taylor expand the root to get $L=\frac 1 n \sum_1^n a_i$ as expected since $GM\to AM$ as $x\to \infty$ as individual differences get washed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may write, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
(x+a_1)\cdot(x+a_2)\cdot...\cdot(x+a_n)&=x^n+(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)\cdot x^{n-1}+O(x^{n-2})\\\\
&=x^n\left(1+\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\\\\
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)\cdot(x+a_2)\cdot...\cdot(x+a_n)}&=x\left(1+\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^{1/n}\\\\
&=x+\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\end{align}
$$ and

> $$
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1)\cdot(x+a_2)\cdot...\cdot(x+a_n)}-x\right)=\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}.
> $$

Comment: That's not a hint, it's a solution.

Comment: Great solution. I just came up with another way of doing this, since I'm still not able to solve using Taylor series expansion (not yet covered by my teacher), and that is by using mean inequality $H\leq G\leq A$ and then using squeeze theorem. I'm currently finding the limit where instead of the geometric mean in the original limit, I put harmonic mean. I hope this works :)

Comment: how to calculate $ \left(1+\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^{1/n}$ ?

Comment: @maplgebra As $u \to 0$, by using a Taylor series one gets $(1+u)^s=1+su+O(u^2)$, then apply it here with $u=\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{x}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$ and $s=\frac{1}{n}$. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

It's more complicated to write in LaTeX, than to solve. Remember that

$$A-B = \frac {A^n - B^n} {A^{n-1} + A^{n-2} B + \dots + A B^{n-2} + B^{n-1}} .$$

Choosing $A = \sqrt[n]{(x+a_1) (x+a_2) \dots (x+a_n)}$ and $B = \sqrt[n] {x^n}$, note that the largest power of $x$ in $A^n - B^n$ is $x^{n-1}$, and it is multiplied by the coefficient $a_1 + \dots + a_n$.

Similarly, looking for the dominant part of $x$ in the denominator, write

$$A^{n-k} \cdot B^{k-1} = [ (x+a_1) (x+a_2) \dots (x+a_n) ] ^{\frac {n-k} n} \cdot (x^n) ^{\frac {k-1} n} = \\ (x^n) ^{\frac {n-k} n} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac {a_1} x \right) \dots \left( 1 + \frac {a_n} x \right)\right] ^{\frac {n-k} n} \cdot (x^n) ^{\frac {k-1} n} = x^{n-1} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac {a_1} x \right) \dots \left( 1 + \frac {a_n} x \right)\right] ^{\frac {n-k} n} .$$

Note that the part between square brackets tends to $1$ when $x \to \infty$ (because $n$, the number of factors, stays fixed and each factor tends to $0$), so $\dfrac {A^{n-k} \cdot B^{k-1}} {x^{n-1}} \to 1$ (i.e $A^{n-k} \cdot B^{k-1}$ behaves asymptotically like $x^{n-1}$ when $x \to \infty$). There are $n$ such terms in the denominator, so $\dfrac {n x^{n-1}} {\text{denominator}} \to 1$.

Putting everything together you get that

$$\sqrt[n]{(x+a_1) (x+a_2) \dots (x+a_n)} - \sqrt[n] {x^n} = A-B = \\ \frac {(a_1 + \dots a_n) x^{n-1} + \text{smaller powers of} \ x} {n x^{n-1}} \frac {n x^{n-1}} {\text{denominator}} \to \frac {a_1 + \dots + a_n} n .$$

Comment: See and: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591694/how-to-find-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-left-sqrtm-prod-i-1mna/591906#591906